# DocBlockr/DoxyDozygen в Sublime Text 3 не подхватывают типы аргументов при парсинге функции

Tags: javascript

[image: Пример функции после парсинга]

Проблема: оно не может подхватить типы переменных, кроме булевого.

Comment: Це не баг, це фича, оказывается

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что это не является каким-либо багом или фичей.

Из-за динамической типизации JS оно не может подхватить типа переменной, максимум по косвенным признакам, по типу `is` в `isMetall`